# How can I use 'window.location.href' with a content area div and still create canonical URL variables for Disqus?

Tags: javascript, disqus

I am using the following script to insert content into a div area...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('div#contentWindow a').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var url = $(this).attr('href');
           $('#contentarea').load(url);
       });
    });
</script>
```

The content that appears in the div area each has it's own file and thus it's own URL.  The content loads through a series of menu button, each loading a different page file into the div area.

Each page file contains the basic Disqus comments embed code.  Disqus requires that each page file has a unique canonical URL to prevent comments repeating in multiple pages.  So, I used what Disqus recommened:

```
this.page.url = window.location.href; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
```

BUT...because I am loading different canonical pages into the same div area on a page, and the parent URL never changes (because of window.location.href, I assume), comments are repeating themselves.

I need Disqus to recognize the canonical URL for the file being loaded into the div area and recognize each page's unique URL so prevent comments from repeating themselves, and I can't figure it out.

Here is a demo of the project I am working on.  Notice that the test comments are repeating in every "channel".

```
http://locallava.com/alpha-ac/
```

Here is the current install of the Disqus script...

```
    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = **window.location.href**; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };

    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    s.src = '//local-lava.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
```

How do I fix this? Thanks everyone.